# How to access an In-Memory Database in Android Emulator from adb shell?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, in-memory-database, adb

I want to view the tables stored in an in-memory database stored in an AVD. I have created the database using super(context, null, null, DATABASE_VERSION); constructor of my DatabaseHelper class and am creating the database using the getWritableDatabase() function.

I then attach the in-memory database using the attach command ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS aux1; but on typing the .schema or .tables command or SELECT name FROM aux1.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';, it does not display any output.

Comment: from device file manager navigate to data/data folder of your application. That't the default location of the database. So first cross check that your database is created or not

Comment: An in-memory database is only visible to the process that creates it. You can't access the same db from a different one (Or even from a different db connection in the same process unless you enable shared-cache mode). If you need that, use a file-based database instead.